# Management of users roles based on granular permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, asp.net-identity

I am trying to code a simple blog using Asp.NET **MVC** Framework using C#.

It is a simple blog where users share posts and comments and administrators can hide, delete and edit posts and comments through an administration panel. So far so good.

I am also trying to give the administrators control over the users permissions where they can assign a user to one role or more. These roles should be definable by the administrators upon their creation, where they can tick a bullet list of granular permissions.

Examples of granular permissions are: hiding posts, deleting them, editing them, blocking a user, validating a newly registered user, etc.
These permissions are hard coded into the application and are fixed.

I am seeking guidance as to how I can define these permissions and roles.

So thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do it by claims or by creating new roles for each of permission you described above and then authorize it against claim or role...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very much depends on your system. I'd create roles for every permission `CanHidePosts`, `CanDeletePosts`, `CanEditPosts`. And use these because all the plumbing is mostly available to you via `AuthorizeAttribute`. But you'll have to give all permissions to admin users - because you you would want admins to be able to do everything without having to add them into every single role.

You can do the same with claims, but you'll have to do a bit more plumbing yourself.

The choice is yours - there is no wrong way here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have trouble seeing how the whole role (which contains several permissions) is stored in the Database (and as a model). Also how that role would be used with the AuthorizeAttribute since its name has just been created by an administrator for instance. Sorry if I am too vague I still struglle with .Net and would love to see it as a whole before jumping into its implementation.

Comment: Roles don't contain permissions. You give access to different actions/controllers depending on a role via `[Authorize("CanDeletePosts")]`. And then you give `CanDeletePosts` role to a user.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I'll try to implement it this wy. Seems to me that claims are somehow more complicated and I have a deadline to meet.